# Três inputs dentro do mesmo form. Consigo fazer suas ações sem sair da pagina (sem dar refresh)?

Tags: ajax

Blz Galera. Tenho três botões dentro do mesmo formulário (cadastrar, alterar e visualizar) e gostaria de fazer as ações dos botões sem sair da pagina. Como consigo fazer isto? Alguns colegas comentaram do Ajax. É possível algum exemplo?

Na caso o formulário está assim:

```
<form id="locadora" name="locadora method="post">

<input type="text" name="txt_titulo" size="38" maxlength="30" style="border-radius: 5px;"/>

<select id="txt_categoria" name="txt_categoria" style="border-radius: 4px;">
<option value="Séries">Séries</option>
<option value="Animes">Animes</option>
<option value="Filmes">Filmes</option>
</select>

<select id="txt_audio" name="txt_audio" style="border-radius: 4px;">
<option value="Dublado e Legendado">Dublado e Legendado</option>
<option value="Dublado">Dublado</option>
<option value="Legendado">Legendado</option>
</select>

<input name="visualizar" type="submit" id="visualizar" value="Visualizar"/>
<input name="alterar" type="submit" id="alterar" value="Alterar"/>
<input name="cadastrar" type="submit" id="cadastrar" value="Cadastrar"/>
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Fala Marcio!
Olha, existem diversas maneiras de se fazer isso.
Acredito que o ideal e mais utilizada é usar JavaScript para gerencias esses eventos dos botões.
Segue um exemplo abaixo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click "Try it" to execute the displayDate() function.</p>

<button id="myBtn">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = displayDate;

function displayDate() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Caso precisar de mais alguns exemplos. Segue o link de referencia da W3S:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp